# Looking for algorithm to extract line network from binary images

Tags: computer-vision, algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for algorithm to extract line network from binary images within LabView](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/looking-for-algorithm-to-extract-line-network-from-binary-images-within-labview)

I would like to create a LabView VI that receives an input image and the RGB-color codes of the powerlines depicted in the image. The output should (eventually) consist of id'd polygonial connections and their coordinates.

Right now i've finished creating a VI that converts the source image to a binary image with the respective line color types extracted into a binary image (see below).

I've been trying to apply some of edge/line finding VIs supplied by LabView Vision, but the results have not been very convincing.

I have considered implementing some sort of vectorization algorithm like '[Straight Line Extraction Using Iterative Total Least Squares Methods](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/vanmieghem/htm/pubs/straightlineextraction_vcir1995.pdf)' or even some sort of line-walking-and-mapping algorithm, but before I do so I'd like to know if there already is some kind of fitting algorithm out there.

Attached you can find examples for the source and binary images.

[image: Source image (in this case a snipped of poland)]
[image: binary image of extracted green lines]
[image: binary image of extracted red lines]

See also the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183187/looking-for-algorithm-to-extract-line-network-from-binary-images-within-labview) version

Comment: Thanks for the edit jonsca, since the original question has been migrated to signal processing now, I've flagged this post as duplicate.